# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'prev' when inserting doubly linked list

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to learn a course on udemy on data structures and algorithms as i am completely new to this so any help would be appreciated and it would be really helpful if the answers were kept simple.
Thanks. I tried contacting the instructor but he would not respond.
I myself to do not see a problem with this code so any advice would greatly help me.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,value=None):
        self.value= value
        self.next= None
        self.prev = None



class DoublyLinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None


    def __iter__(self):
        node = self.head
        while node:
            yield node
            node = node.next
            

    def createDLL(self,value):
        newNode = Node(value)
        newNode.next = None
        newNode.prev = None
        self.head = newNode
        self.tail = newNode

    def insert(self,value,location):
        if self.head is None:
            print("Linked list does not exist")
        else:
            newNode = Node(value)
            if location == 0:
                newNode.prev = None
                newNode.next = self.head
                self.head.prev = newNode
                self.head = newNode
            elif location == 1:
                newNode.next = None
                newNode.next = self.head
                self.head.prev = newNode
                self.head = newNode
            else:
                tempNode = self.head
                index = 0
                while index < location - 1:
                    tempNode = tempNode.next
                    index += 1

                newNode.next = tempNode.next
                newNode.prev = tempNode
                newNode.next.prev = newNode
                tempNode.next = newNode
                





doublyLL = DoublyLinkedList()
doublyLL.createDLL(1)
doublyLL.insert(2,1)
doublyLL.insert(3,2)
```

I am trying to insert a new node but it keeps on returning this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\doublylinkedlist.py", line 66, in <module>
    doublyLL.insert(3,2)
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\doublylinkedlist.py", line 55, in insert
    newNode.next.prev = newNode
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'prev'
```

I am trying to learn a course on udemy on data structures and algorithms as i am completely new to this so any help would be appreciated and it would be really helpful if the answers were kept simple.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your `else` clause needs correction.

Also, you really do not need the `elif` clause. The `else` clause should be able to cover this case too.

So, get rid of the `elif` clause, and correct your `else` clause as below:

```
            else:
                tempNode = self.head
                index = 0
                while index < location - 1:
                    tempNode = tempNode.next
                    index += 1

                newNode.next = tempNode.next
                newNode.prev = tempNode
                if newNode.next:
                    newNode.next.prev = newNode
                tempNode.next = newNode
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always make sure that when you access an attribute (like `next`), the object on which you access it, is not `None`.

You get an error on:

```
newNode.next.prev = newNode
```

When `newNode` is about to become the last node in the list, then `newNode.next` is `None` (which is OK), and so the above assignment should not happen at all:

```
if newNode.next:
    newNode.next.prev = newNode
```

Some other issues / remarks:

- It is not necessary to treat `location == 1` as a separate case.
- You should update `self.tail` if the new node becomes the last node in the list
- It is not common to have a `CreateDLL` method like you did. This is because you *already* have a Doubly linked list, even when it is empty. Consider that an empty linked list is still a linked list, just like an empty standard list is still a list. There should not need to be a separate method to insert the first value into it.
- As a nice addition, you could define `__str__` methods on both `Node` and `DoublyLinkedList` classes, so that you can just `print` a doubly linked list instance

Result:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,value=None):
        self.value= value
        self.next= None
        self.prev = None

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)


class DoublyLinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None

    def __iter__(self):
        node = self.head
        while node:
            yield node
            node = node.next            

    def __str__(self):
        return "←→".join(map(str, self))

    def insert(self, value, location):
        newNode = Node(value)
        if location == 0:
            newNode.next = self.head
            if self.head:
                self.head.prev = newNode
            self.head = newNode
        else:
            tempNode = self.head
            while location > 1:
                tempNode = tempNode.next
                location -= 1

            newNode.next = tempNode.next
            newNode.prev = tempNode
            if newNode.next:
                newNode.next.prev = newNode
            tempNode.next = newNode
        if not newNode.next:
            self.tail = newNode
                
doublyLL = DoublyLinkedList()
doublyLL.insert(1, 0)  # No need to call CreateDLL
doublyLL.insert(2, 1)
doublyLL.insert(3, 2)

print(doublyLL)  # 1←→2←→3
```